# Automatically logged out as soon as I log in

Tags: login, files, home-directory

Ubuntu 16.04 logs me out automatically after I log in. This thing started after I tried to extract Matlab to a folder in my home directory which in turn got extracted to the home directory. Please can anyone give me a clue to what is happening to my computer?

Comment: Is your home directory full as the result of your attempted extraction?

Answer (score 0):

Press control + alt + f2, and this will drop you to a terminal. Then login and run

```
rm .Xauthority
service lightdm restart
```

and try logging in again, this fixes that problem for me 99% of the time.

 If that doesn't fix your problem, try

```
apt install --reinstall lightdm
```

Also, although some people will tell you to install gdm, I find that this prevents my computer from booting, and just causes more problems. However, if all else fails, it may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting lightdm.

`sudo service lightdm restart`
If that doesent work try installing gdm
    `sudo apt install gdm`
    `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`
    `sudo service lightdm stop`
    press crtl + alt + f2, login then type
    `sudo service gdm start`

 This should fix your problem. I had the same issue and this fixed it.

Comment: I'd recommend trying my answer before this, as this sometimes causes boot issues.

Comment: I have no clue what NerdOfLinux is talking about... It should not cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Alt+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to a text console. Enter your username at the prompt, then your password. You will get a command line shell prompt.

Find out the files that were extracted from the archive. It's probably one of these that's causing the problem. If the archive is a zip file, run

```
unzip -l /path/to/matlab.zip >/var/tmp/files
```

If it's a `.tar.*` file, run

```
tar tf /path/to/matlab.tar.gz >/var/tmp/files
```

Then go through the archive and try to guess which file is the culprit. It's probably a [file whose name starts with a dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-file), or a file in a directory whose name starts with a dot. The following command lists those files:

```
grep '^\.' /var/tmp/files
```

Don't delete any files — move them to a temporary directory, so you can move them back if it turns out that they should stay.

If you've already *deleted* some files then it's another matter. You can recover from this, but it might require removing a reference to the offending file somewhere, and figuring out which file is the culprit can be difficult.

There may be clues in a log file. Look at the file `.xsession-errors` and see if there are any clues:

```
less ~/.xsession-errors
```

Looking at recently-changed files can also give a clue. Run the following command to list dot files changed less than 123 minutes ago (adjust the figure as desired):

```
find ~/.[^.]* -ctime -123 -type f
```

If you aren't sure how to interpret a log message, or what a file is about, edit your question and add all relevant information (e.g. copy-paste the log message). If you can't access Stack Exchange from that account, use a different user account, or use a text mode web browser such as w3m (`sudo apt-get install w3m`) and upload to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This solution in the long post by Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' below solved my problem:

There may be clues in a log file. Look at the file .xsession-errors and see if there are any clues:

```
less ~/.xsession-errors
```

My problem it seems was caused by Variety not being able to get a new picture in a google search at startup.